# JPA/REST Application as a .war file?

Tags: jpa, war, spring-tool-suite

Utilizing STS, I have recently created a full-stack application that is one half REST (interacting with the JS front-end) and the other half JPA (interacting with the MySQL db back-end). When I was ready to upload my application to the cloud, I created a .war file from the REST application.

[.war file created from REST portion of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU3Uy.png)

However, once uploaded to the cloud, the application has been facing issues. While the front-end is functional, the app appears to be unable to communicate with the database, and I'm wondering if I am supposed to create a separate .war file for the JPA portion as well, or whether the JPA portion is automatically packaged in the existing .war file as laid out in the `settings.gradle` file.

```
rootProject.name = 'RESTCompleteAg'

includeFlat 'JPACompleteAg'
```

Comment: You can unpack the war file to see what is included and what not. Did you create the war file from the running the build of the project from the command line?

Comment: I did so utilizing Spring Tool Suite:

Right-click on REST project > Export > Web> WAR File

Comment: Creating the WAR file from the command line executing the regular build works fine?